# Java VisualVM. Что происходит с памятью?

Tags: java

Есть код, где высчитываю оптимальный набор.
Посмотрел по профайлеру, как понимаю, потребление памяти растет, потом происходит уборка мусора, опять растёт, ... . Кто эту память съедает?
Он отработал и всё:

```
static int[] greedyAlgorithm(int[] res, int currentValue, int currentPos) {
    int[] result = res.clone();

    if(currentValue < 0) {
        currentPos--;
        resultSet.addCheckUniqueness(result);
        if(currentPos < 0)
            return null;
        currentValue = currentPos;
    }

    do {
        greedyAlgorithm(result, currentValue - 1, currentPos - 1);
        result[currentValue]++;
    } while (getSum(result));
    result[currentValue]--;

    greedyAlgorithm(result, currentValue - 1, currentPos);

    return result;
}
```

Ну и main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("начало");
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    calculation();

    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    System.out.println("конец");
}
```

1. Программа ждет enter
2. `greedyAlgorithm` отрабатывает несколько десятков раз, происходит вывод информации в консоль
3. Программа ждет enter
   Откуда берется пила на графике(до начала и после отработки метода)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD_1**:
Все глобальные переменные:

```
    private static Integer height;
    private static final int[] w = {80, 300, 600, 900};
    private static final int[] list = {
            2100, 2430, 1570, 1940, 2070, 1160, 1900, 1030, 1110, 1240, 1870, 1890, 1760, 1950, 1830, 1720,
            520, 590, 720, 410, 550, 180, 304, 470, 540, 760, 876, 354, 80, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500, 1800,
            2100, 2400, 2700, 3000, 3300, 3600, 3900, 4200, 4500, 4800, 5100, 5400, 5700, 6000, 6300, 6600,
            6900, 7200, 10, 30, 35, 40, 47, 50, 68, 74, 85, 95, 110, 115, 210, 230, 240, 270, 320, 370, 470,
            550, 640, 730, 890};
//наследуется от HashSet, только добавлен новый метод вставки
    private static HashSetForGreedyAlgorithm resultSet = new HashSetForGreedyAlgorithm();
    private static HashSetForGreedyAlgorithm resultSet50 = new HashSetForGreedyAlgorithm();
```

Comment: Я думаю это все `nextLine()`. Если порыться внутри класса `Scanner`, то видно метод `nextLine()` в бесконечном цикле выделяет переменную String в которую пишет результат вызова `String var3 = this.findPatternInBuffer(var1, var2);`. Я думаю отсюда все и идет. Чтобы подтвердить это или опровергнуть, замените `nextLine` на `Thread.sleep` и посмотрите что будет. Еще это может быть overhead от самой VisualVM.

Comment: @Uraty nextLine() добавил когда хотел посмотреть на график по другому. Если поставить точку останова в дебаге на sysout в начале и конце, то происходит то же самое - пилообразный график.

Comment: как вы думаете, что делает `res.clone()` в каждом вызове рекурсивного метода?

Comment: @etki Копирует массив). Пилы возникают до и после отработки рекурсивного метода.

Comment: @Uraty Thread.sleep тот же результат.

Comment: Кроме вашего main-треда, в JVM происходит еще иного всяких забавных вещей в других тредах, например, при запуске могут грузиться локали, классы, и прочие веселые вещи. Они тоже набивают хип, который время от времени очищается, если вы про это. Вы можете в той же VisualVM снять дамп и посмотреть, кто висит в памяти и какие еще треды работают, кроме основного.

Comment: @etki может... там какие-то непонятные массивы байтов, чаров и объектов постоянно увеличиваются и собираются.

Comment: @etki всё, это VisualVM делает такую пакость: https://habrahabr.ru/post/269621/

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- используйте Flight Recorder чтобы исключить влияние инструментирования.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить VisualVM / JDK. У меня локальное подключение (не через JMX) со спящей программой имело нулевой рост хипа. Впрочем, еще раз повторюсь, что ничего страшного в росте хипа нет.

Answer (score 0):

я конечно точный ответ не знаю но расскажу что сам понял.
Как я заметил это из-за того, что если приложение запущено, оно работает и постоянно создаются какие-то классы, то есть в процессе жизни приложения создается очень много объектов классов, которые использовались и через время больше не нужны. Со временем они накапливаются и как только используемая heap space (по графикам предполагаю что это график heap space) доходит до определенного лимита то срабатывает GC и очищает мусор, и происходит падение синий области (used heap space).